# What is the parameter $instance_id in the function Block::setVisibilityConfig?

Tags: 8, blocks

I need to programatically set the visibility of a block. I've loaded the block, and I know I need to use the `Block::setVisibilityConfig` method, but I don't know what the `$instance_id` variable is.

Does anyone know what to pass here to the function?

Comment: It's [documented](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!src!Entity!Block.php/function/Block%3A%3AsetVisibilityConfig/8.2.x). You pass an instance of a visibility condition object (which implements [ConditionInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Condition%21ConditionInterface.php/interface/ConditionInterface/8.2.x))

Comment: Hi @Clive, thanks for your reply, but I don't understand it. I have the following code: use Drupal\block\Entity\Block;
$block = Block::load('sitebranding');
$block->setRegion('content');
$block->save(); What can I add to call that function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it. Example:

```
use Drupal\block\Entity\Block;

function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables)
{
    $block = Block::load('sitebranding');
    $block->setRegion('content');

    $visibility = $block->getVisibility();

    if (isset($visibility['request_path']['pages']))
    {
       unset($visibility['request_path']['pages']);
       $visibility['request_path']['negate'] = 0; 
       // $visibility['request_path']['pages'] = '/node/2';
       $visibility['request_path']['pages'] = \Drupal::config('mymodule.settings')->get('services_block_path_visibility');
       $block->setVisibilityConfig('request_path', $visibility['request_path']);
       $block->save();
    }
}
```