# Programmatically set the block visibility

Tags: 8, blocks

I set *Configuration type* to *Block* and selected my custom block to export the configuration from *development/configuration/single/export*. I got the following block visibility configuration.

```yaml
visibility:
  _menu_position:
    id: _menu_position
    _menu_position:
      'main:menu_link_content:016650bb-ecd4-43e4-9d04-fef05ebcf186': 'main:menu_link_content:016650bb-ecd4-43e4-9d04-fef05ebcf186'
      'main:menu_link_content:2d195963-d98d-4f02-8129-6498c5db4b87': 'main:menu_link_content:2d195963-d98d-4f02-8129-6498c5db4b87'
```

For this, I have used the following function.

```php
function placeBlock(EntityInterface $entity) {

    $config = \Drupal::configFactory();
    $settings = [
        'plugin' => '_block_module_block', // Set the plugin id
        'region' => 'header', // Set region to header
        'id' => $entity->id() . '-_bm_autoheader', // Use the page id and the module name for machine name
        'theme' => $config->get('system.theme')->get('default'),
        'label' => $entity->label(), // Use the page label
        'visibility' => [],
        'weight' => 0,
        'label_display' => 0, // disable label
        'page_id' => $entity->id(), // Reference page
    ];
    $values = [];
    foreach (['region', 'id', 'theme', 'plugin', 'weight', 'visibility'] as $key) {
        $values[$key] = $settings[$key];
        // Remove extra values that do not belong in the settings array.
        unset($settings[$key]);
    }
  
    foreach ($values['visibility'] as $id => $visibility) {
         $values['visibility'][$id]['id'] = $id;
    }

    $values['settings'] = $settings;
    $block = Block::create($values);
    $block->save();
}
```

In my case, `$visibility` gets a `NULL` value.

```yaml
langcode: de
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - _block_module
  theme:
    - _drupal_theme
id: 57148-_bm_autoheader
theme: _drupal_theme
region: header
weight: 0
provider: null
plugin: _block_module_block
settings:
  id: _block_module_block
  label: 'Header Contact'
  provider: _block_module
  label_display: '0'
  page_id: '57148'
visibility: {  }
```

I need help to understand the block visibility setting. How does it work in Drupal 8? How can I programmatically set it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply rewrite the yaml in php. Can't help with the format of this visibility plugin, never seen this before, but you can see an example for the path plugin here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251143/create-a-custom-block-programmatically-and-specify-region-and-pages-on-which-cre

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution, set the visibility configuration by the following function using $menuLinkItem->uuid().

> function setVisibilityConfig($instance_id, array $configuration)

```
$block->setVisibilityConfig('_menu_position', array('id' => '_menu_position',
        '_menu_position'=> [
              'main:menu_link_content:'.$menuLinkItem->uuid() => 'main:menu_link_content:'.$menuLinkItem->uuid()
            ],
        'negate' => null,
        )
    );
```

Thanks, @SumitMadan for helping out to understand the visibility concept.

Comment: This also with the same topic. 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/213527/79720